# Unfriendly build message

Tags: c#, .net, build

I can build my application in VS 2012 on my local machine and run it OK.

But I get this message;

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

It does not tell me which assemply is the problem, and I cannot build to the build server using TFS 2010.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Do you have incremental build and get enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set "detailed" for build output. In Visual Studio menu:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity -> Detailed

If you wan to get the same in log file, then do the same things in combo below.

[image]

Comment: Heh.. never knew this option existed. I will be enabling this in our projects at work on Monday!